# Как результат представить в виде таблицы?

Tags: c++

Как результат представить в виде таблицы в данном задании?

Составить программу для вычисления функции F(x) на отрезке [a,b] с шагом h. Результат представить в виде таблицы, первый столбец которой - значение аргумента, второй - соответствующее значение функции.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double a, b, h;
    cout << "Введите a: " , cin >> a;
    cout << "Введите b: " , cin >> b;
    cout << "Введите шаг h: ", cin >> h;

    for (double x = a; x <= b; x += h) 
        cout << x << "\t" << tan (x / 2) + 2 * cos (x) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пр вставке кода программы нужно выделить его мышкой и нажать на кнопку 101 010, тогда будет правильное форматирование.

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Ваш код и так выводит результаты вычислений в виде таблицы, где в первом столбце - значение аргумента, а во втором столбце - значение функции.

Comment: хм,у меня в строку выводит,можете выложить скриншот?

Comment: Зачем?! Просто запустите Ваш код в Visual Studio. "<< endl" - это обеспечивает перевод строки.

Comment: так у меня выводит результат выводит в строку,а должны быть столбцы со значениями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ g++ sample.cc -o sample && ./sample

Введите a: 1  
Введите b: 2  
Введите шаг h: 0.5  
1    1.62691  
1.5  1.07307  
2    0.725114
```

Comment: ээм,извиняюсь за вопрос,но куда это вписать?